# why do i create a view per action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

Hi; i am a Asp.net software developer. i try to learn asp.net mvc. But i face to face strange thing. My contoller method name must be the same as view name or reverse. this is strange! Look please my _Layout:

```
    <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Article", "GetAll", "Article")</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

article view page need GetAll method also need GetAll.cshtml. My desire: my view page name must independent of controller class'method name. My Controller:
[image]

My solution :

[image]

i think that Asp.net mvc is strange.  i dislike controller' action name  name must the same as view page name? how to make it? i think that View name  must independent form any name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that by default your view name must be the same as your action name. However, this is easy to  change. You can just called [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310.aspx) of the View method in the controller and pass in whatever view name you want:

```
return View("SomeViewName",articles);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be the same as the name of your method. By Default MVC3 will look for a `View` with the same name but you can create a `View` with ANY name and tell MVC to return that View:

```
return View("MyView",articles);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 comments:

- GetAll() in MVC would typically be called Index (as in articles index)
- You could name your Method something and return a view with a different name,

  ```
  public ActionMethod GetAll()
  {
    return View("Index");
  }
  ```